# Data truncation: Invalid JSON text: "The document is empty." at position 0 in value for column column_name | quiljs contents

Tags: java, mysql, json, quill, delta

I am using QuillJs wysiwyg editor, it uses json to represent the data which its editor contains.
i want to save its content in mysql database.
i am using Java Spring Boot as server side language.
(i am a beginner)
so i have JSONObject (org.json.JSONObject) in my entity class `private JSONObject data;` which will contain the data that quill's editor contain.
i am getting the editor's contents by javascript like this:     `document.getElementById("datajso").value=  JSON.stringify(quill.getContents().ops);`

`datajso` is mapped to the  `JSONObject data` by using thymeleaf.

so when i take image from my pc storage and put it on my editor, quill converts the image to base64 code.
i am saving the base64 code to mysql.
i saved an image(which is in base64) of 1.08MB to the database, it gets saved in database as base64 code.
for this `JSONObject data` i have JSON type in MySql.

so i saved this 1.08MB image successfully, but when i tried with another image which is of 1.84MB. i get the below error

```
Failed to complete request: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
2020-07-31 23:29:53.612 ERROR 92352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Invalid JSON text: "The document is empty." at position 0 in value for column 'create_content.data'.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
```

i have tried to use String, LONGTEXT instead of JSON,  type but i am not able to get rid of this error.
i need help.

i tried to copy the base64 text of that 1.86MB image(2mn+ characters) and tried to execute an insert query in mysql workbench, but there it gave me this error:
please note that in the editor the data is not only images its text also.

`Error Code: 3140. Invalid JSON text: "Invalid encoding in string." at position 2726003 in value for column 'create_content.data'.`

this is how my insert query looks like:
insert into korenani.create_content values(11,'[{"insert":{"image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QL+RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAANAAABBAABAAAAwA8AAAEBBAABAAAARAcAAA8BAgAI(more characters of this base64 code are there but not able to add the actual query)}

please help me get rid of this error.
if there is any other good approach to save QuillJs editor's data into database, please let me know.
This is my first "Post" request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance